# Confusion regarding SQL query

Tags: mysql, database

How to display employees name from a employee list?

Whose name start with particular letter, using SQL.

For example: names starting with "a".

I tried but couldn't find any answer because I was unable to figure it out how to separate letters using query

Table structure

```
create table book_info 
(
     bookid int primarykey, 
     author varchar(20), 
     publications varchar(20), 
     price int
)
```

Comment: **WHAT** database? How does your table look (columns and their data types)? Can you show us some **sample data**

Comment: It is a library database

Comment: Table named book_info and one of the colum name is author.

Comment: Question is to Display author of the book starting by letter a

Comment: And data type is of varchar(20)

Comment: I was asking whether you're using **Oracle**, or **SQL Server**, or **MySQL**, or **Postgres** - which database **product** are you using? Also: can you please post the **complete** SQL script that creates your table?

Comment: Using mysql in command prompt!!! And to create table, create table book_info (bookid int primarykey, author varchar (20), publications varchar (20), price int) ,insert 5 values to the table. To display author of the books starting by letter a!

Answer (score 1):

```
select <employees name> from <employee list> where <employees name> like 'a%'
```

**if starting with a particular character**

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> where <column_name> like '<char/string>%'
```

**if ending with a particular character**

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> where <column_name> like '%<char/string>'
```

**if a column has a particular character at any position**

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> where <column_name> like '%<char/string>%'
```